# Best practice for harvesting COM file file to WiX fragment

Tags: wix, wix3

I have made a dynamic deployment project based on WiX 3.0, that uses mainly HEAT to consume directories in dynamic way (files + DLL that need to be registered).

The question is that i don't understand what attribute should i use in heat in term of the COM, Should i use "-SCOM" or not (what does it effect e.g. patching)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

heat.exe automatically harvests self registration from DLLs when harvesting directories. heat.exe does not currently support capturing self registering executables.

Comment: When i heat a self reg file i can see that even if i set -SCOM i still get the registry of the heat, why?